# Google Drive File Download api in node js cannot working?

Tags: node.js, google-api

I am using google drive file download api for download the file from google drive.

I am using the following code,

```
var fileId = '1RDrrFGV2fM7jvnxGFileId';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('./sample.xlsx');

drive.files.get({fileId: fileId, alt: 'media'}, {responseType: 'stream'},
function(err, res){
    res.data
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', err => {
        console.log('Error', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
}
);
```

Downloaded file was empty, How to get the file data.

Comment: Please edit your question and include any error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a another solution for download the google drive file. use the following code snippet

```
var downloadfile="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=" + fileId

return downloadfile;
```

Browse the downloadfile url to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

drive.files.get will return only metadata of the file. Since you're trying to download file and retrieve the content you should use

```
drive.files.export({fileId: fileId, mimeType: <MIME type of your file>})
```

You can refer the client documentation https://apis-nodejs.firebaseapp.com/drive/index.html

Comment: yes i am getting the error "drive.files.export(...).on is not a function"

Comment: I was getting the same error "TypeError: drive.files.export(...).on is not a function". The solution I found was to call it like this `const res = await drive.files.export( { fileId: id, mimeType: 'application/pdf' }, { responseType: 'stream' }); res.data.pipe(dest);` where `dest = fs.createWriteStream('myfile.pdf');`. The example on Google APIs website for node is not working.